# How to show Google Maps Directions in tabs or div that has display:none

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, tabs, map-directions

When I'm loading a Google Map (v3) with Directions into a div that is hidden from the user, the resulting map is not zoomed and centered correctly. I tried firing a `resize` event but that did only partially solve the problem.

Usually when loading a map with directions, the API automatically finds the optimal view (ie. zoom level and center) as to show the entire journey. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Please see [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mB6AZ/1/)

```
<button id="show">Show</button>
<div id="a">
   <div id="map_wrapper" style="display:none">
      <div id="map_canvas" style="height: 354px; width:713px;"></div>
   </div>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&callback=initialize"></script>
  <script>
  var directionsService,
      directionsDisplay,
      map;

    function initialize() {

      directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
      directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(); 
      var mapOptions = { mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, disableDefaultUI: true }
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
      directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

      var start = 'New York, NY';
      var end = 'Chicago, IL';
      var request = { origin: start, destination: end, travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING };
      directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
      });
    }
  </script>
</div>
```

And the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#show').on('click', function() {
        $('#map_wrapper').show();
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify  the ready-function as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
        $('#show').on('click', function() {
            $('#map_wrapper').show();
            google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, "resize",function(){
              try{this.fitBounds(directionsDisplay.getDirections().routes[0].bounds)
              }catch(e){}
            });
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        });
      });
```

It will , when a route is available inside the map, set the bounds of the map to the bounds of the route.

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/c2pC3/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/c2pC3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize map after button click: remove callback, сall `initialize()` on button click. http://jsfiddle.net/mB6AZ/2/

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but in my case the whole HTML is loaded with AJAX so I need to keep the callback. This question is actually a spin-off of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229695/google-maps-api-throws-uncaught-referenceerror-google-is-not-defined-only-whe

Comment: May be you can hide this block from user without setting `display:none`, like that http://jsfiddle.net/boko/mB6AZ/5/

Answer (score 0):

Save a copy of the DirectionsRoute LatLngBounds and then fit the map to those bounds once it has been resized.

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mB6AZ/8/)

```
var bounds;

directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      bounds = response.routes[0].bounds;
    }
});

$(document).ready(function (e) {
  $('#show').on('click', function () {
    $('#map_wrapper').show(0, function () {
      // this will fire once the map resize completes
      google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function () {
        this.fitBounds(bounds);
      });
      google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
    });
  });
});
```