# Google Charts change data javascript

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how to change the array of data passed into a chart and the title based upon a java script drop down.

I would like a dropdown to switch between ConsultingSales and Lifesciences and also have the title change. Been putzing around with this and cannot figure it out. Please help.

Thanks

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">


                var LifeSciencesSales =   [  ['Month', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
                ['Jan-12',1500,464.0070717],
                ['Feb-12',800,578.2656461],
                ['Mar-12',900,220.8059709],
                ['Apr-12',1000,534.1582816],
                ['May-12',505,768.0671543],
                ['Jun-12',958,181.6553778],
                ['Jul-12',2000,436.6480464],
                ['Aug-12',1300,108.9466581],
                ['Sept-12',1500,930.5872168],
                ['Oct-12',800,902.2438355],
                ['Dec-12',958,621.7321969]
                ]

                var ConsultingSales =   [  ['Month', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
                ['Jan-12',455,44.0070717],
                ['Feb-12',800,578.2656461],
                ['Mar-12',545,220.8059709],
                ['Apr-12',1000,534.1582816],
                ['May-12',505,768.0671543],
                ['Jun-12',876,181.6553778],
                ['Jul-12',875,436.6480464],
                ['Aug-12',1300,108.9466581],
                ['Sept-12',1000,930.5872168],
                ['Oct-12',1345,902.2438355],
                ['Dec-12',895,621.7321969]
                ]   
                      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
                      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
                      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart1);
                      function drawChart() {
                        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(LifeSciencesSales);

                        var options = {
                          title: "Sales"
                        };

                        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                        chart.draw(data, options);
                      }





        </script>
      </head>


        <div id="chart_div" style="width: 1200px; height: 400px;"></div>

        <div id="chart_div1" style="width: 1200px; height: 400px;"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Are you using any external frame work here ? If so , what is it ?

Comment: no sir im not using any

Comment: Then what's `google.load`, `google.setOnLoadCallback` functions ? They don't appear to be inbuilt js fns ....Have you provided the whole code layout ?

Comment: sorry new to this stuff

Comment: Are you sure there is no other js involved here ? I have fiddled this : http://jsfiddle.net/YjcVm/  and i still get this error : `Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined ` .

Comment: You are not doing it right , see this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229695/google-maps-api-throws-uncaught-referenceerror-google-is-not-defined-only-whe . You need to call asynchronously .