# getting "google not defined" in apache cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-maps

I'm trying to show a map in my APP but i'm getting "google not defined"

My index.js looks like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#home_button', (function () {

        var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(-17.391919993615, -66.155978093418);
        var opciones = { center: coords, zoom: 15, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };
        var mapa = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), opciones);
        var marcador = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: coords,
            map: mapa,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP

        })


        getRefresh();
    }));
```

And my index.html header looks like:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
    <access origin="*" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">        
    <script src="../../Jquery/prettify.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDGGvPKPbRdqHqS98CK8BShmF7VLBHepcQ&sensor=false"></script>
```

After that I just show it in a`<div id="map">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This applies to all platforms. This is happening because the Google API library hasn't been loaded yet and it's being called already. Load it asynchronously as suggested in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229695/google-maps-api-throws-uncaught-referenceerror-google-is-not-defined-only-whe). Make sure the googleapis for maps is loaded first before using it:

```
<body>
    <div id="floating-panel">
        <input id="address" type="textbox" value="Sydney, NSW">
        <input id="submit" type="button" value="Geocode">
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
        function initMap() {
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 8,
            center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644}
            });

            });
        }
    </script>
    //load it first using async
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB8X7wnW7veRvTnS1xGzuxDaIGuQlHMn8I&callback=initMap">
    </script>
</body>
```

----another sample------

```
//load googleapis for maps first
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
//your js file that will use it
<script type ="text/javascript" src ="SomeJScriptfile.js"></script>
```

not

```
<script type ="text/javascript" src ="SomeJScriptfile.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
```