# Map shows TypeError: $ is not a function in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, google-maps

i am trying to display google map in website. i don't want to use embed method so, used this using async defer method.

Strange thing is my code works fine in when in html file but, when i use it in wordpress i get TypeError: $ is not a function error.

[image]

How come no type error in html file and typeError when i used in wordpress?

```
 <script>
  var rating;
  var address;
  var name;
  var infoWindow = null;
  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapDiv'), {
      center: {lat: 33.531495, lng: -88.42207},
      zoom: 19
    });
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.getDetails({
      placeId: 'ChIJJdJXNmjphogRo-W21kkhbJg'
    }, function(place, status) {
      if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        rating = place.rating;
        name = place.name;

        //var labelIndex = 50;
        address = "<div>" + place.formatted_address + "</div>"
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: place.geometry.location,

        });

          infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' +
          place.formatted_address + '</div>');

          infowindow.open(map, marker);


         google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function(e) {

// Prevents card from being added more than once (i.e. when page is resized and google maps re-renders)
if ( $( ".place-card" ).length === 0 ) {
$(".gm-style").append('<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 34px;"> <div style="margin: 10px; padding: 1px; -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.298039) 0px 1px 4px -1px; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.298039) 0px 1px 4px -1px; border-radius: 2px; background-color: white;"> <div> <div class="place-card place-card-large"> <div class="place-desc-large"> <div class="place-name"></div><div class="image-place"><img id="photoLocation" src="" style="position: static; top: 0px;left: 0px;width: 175px;height: 165px;"></div><div class="address"></div></div><div class="navigate"> <div class="navigate"> <a class="navigate-link" href="https://www.google.com/maps/dir//33.53151,-88.422063/@33.53151,-88.422063,18z" target="_blank"> <div class="icon navigate-icon"></div><div class="navigate-text"> Directions </div></a> </div></div><div class="review-box"> <div id="review-number" class="review-number"></div><a href="http://www.google.co.in/search?q=Porter,+Singley,+%26+Crane+Family+Dentistry,+2900+Bluecutt+Rd+%232,+Columbus,+MS+39705,+EE.+UU.&ludocid=10983190192268436899#lrd=0x8886e9683657d225:0x986c2149d6b6e5a3,1" class="review-box-link" target="_blank">Reviews</a> </div><div class="saved-from-source-link" style="display:none"> </div><div class="maps-links-box-exp"> <div class="time-to-location-info-exp" style="display:none"> <span class="drive-icon-exp experiment-icon"></span><a class="time-to-location-text-exp" style="display:none" target="_blank"></a><a class="time-to-location-text-exp" style="display:none" target="_blank"></a> </div><div class="google-maps-link"> <a href="https://www.google.com.py/maps/place/Porter,+Singley,+%26+Crane+Family+Dentistry/@33.53151,-88.4242517,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x8886e9683657d225:0x986c2149d6b6e5a3!8m2!3d33.53151!4d-88.422063?hl=es-419" target="_blank">View larger map</a> </div></div></div></div>');
    //$(".review-number").append(rating);
    $("#review-number").append(rating);
       fillCard(place);
       //function to resize the map, responsive.
       google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
            var center = googleMap.getCenter();
            google.maps.event.trigger(googleMap, "resize");
            googleMap.setCenter(center);
        });
   }
  });


      }
    });
              function fillCard(place){
                 var photos = place.photos;
                 var countRatig = rating.toString().slice(0,1);
                $(".address").append(address);
                $(".place-name").append(name);
                $("#photoLocation").attr("src", photos[1].getUrl({'maxWidth': 175, 'maxHeight': 138}))
                for (var i=0; i<countRatig; ++i ){
                    $("#review-number:nth-child(1)").append('<div class="icon rating-star rating-full-star"></div>');
                }
      }

  }
</script>
```

Comment: Make sure your jQuery `<script>` tag is in your `<head>`.

Comment: I tried that too. tried most solutions by googling @PHPglue

Comment: Add [this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/danielpataki/1888a154b37133479e4049ee943e0fb7/raw/53edba1204b0822885a055cfca2ee55d5676f427/enqueue-backend.php) code in your `functions.php` file of current theme. Don't forget to change the `/js/my-great-script.js` to [this link](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js)

Comment: @AniketSahrawat but wordpress core jquery is already there. And i still enqueued the script. but map is not showing. But typeError gone now giving error "ReferenceError: googleMap is not defined"

Comment: Make sure you have the google map api source js, or visit [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?csw=1#HelloWorld) to read the helloworld example.

Comment: @NehaAgra  this thread  might help you to resolve 'Uncaught ReferenceError: googleMap is not defined' 
  error :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229695/google-maps-api-throws-uncaught-referenceerror-google-is-not-defined-only-whe

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `jQuery` instead of `$` because wordpress use `jQuery.noConflict()` mode if I good remember.

Example:

`if ( jQuery( ".place-card" ).length === 0 ) { ...`

Comment: maybe this is stupid question, but do you add a jQuery js file before doing this script?

Comment: Yes @Przemek. wordpress core jquery is there in header. and my js and google map api js is in body.

Answer (score 0):

Change every  $ symbol into jQuery

$ is not supported by wordpress

Comment: doing that giving 'Uncaught ReferenceError: googleMap is not defined'

Answer (score 0):

Better put the whole function in a document ready function. So the scripts executes after the page has been loaded. And you're able to keep the $ sign like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

  // Your function goes here...
  if ( $( ".place-card" ).length === 0 ) {
   //...
  }

});
```