# No result from searching using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I wrote this in google apps script to allow me to open a popup player for youtube in google docs. The other files work fine but this does not

The issue is that the search engine and the UI seem to work, but there is no result from searching, no matter how long I wait. if anyone could point out my mistake and tell me how to fix it that'd be awesome.

```js
function embed(cacheKey, resourceId, resourceType) {

  const progress = document.querySelector("#progress");
  progress.style.display = "block";

  console.log(cacheKey, resourceId, resourceType);

  var text;

  let checked = document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:checked').value;

  if (checked === 'string') {
    text = document.querySelector('input[name="link-text"]').value;
  }

  let prefs = {
    "type": checked,
    "string": text
  };

  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(data) {

    if (data.success) {
      document.querySelector('#result').innerText = "Video linked!";
      setTimeout(function() {
        document.querySelector('#result').innerText = "";
      }, 3000);
    }

    if (data.type === "copy" && data.url) {
      navigator.permissions.query({
        name: "clipboard-write"
      }).then(result => {
        if (result.state == "granted" || result.state == "prompt") {
          navigator.clipboard.writeText(data.url);
          alert('URL copied to clipboard');
        }
      });
    }

    progress.style.display = "none";

  }).DTApi('DT', 'embed', cacheKey, prefs, resourceId, resourceType);

}

function previewEmbed(cacheKey, resourceId, resourceType) {

  const progress = document.querySelector("#progress");
  progress.style.display = "block";

  console.log(cacheKey, resourceId, resourceType);
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(result) {

    let container = document.querySelector("#preview");

    let data = JSON.parse(result);

    console.log(data)

    console.log('Trying to preview: ' + Object.keys(data))

    let settings = function(id, title) {

      const template = "<div class='settings'> \
                             <h2>Settings</h2> \
                             <p>How do you want to link your video?</p> \
                             <input type='radio' id='copy-radio' name='embed-type' value='copy' /><label for='copy-radio'>Copy link to clipboard</label/> \
                             <br /> \
                             <input type='radio' id='thumbnail-radio' name='embed-type' value='thumbnail' /><label for='thumbnail-radio'>Thumbnail</label> \
                             <br /> \
                             <input type='radio' id='toggle' name='embed-type' value='string' /><label for='toggle'>Text</label> \
                             <input type='text' id='link-text' name='link-text' value='" + title + "' /> \
                             <div id='settings-action'> \
                             <button class='action' onclick='embed(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.dataset.cachekey, this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.dataset.resourceid, this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.dataset.resourcetype)'>Get Video</button> \
                             <button onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode)'>Close</button> \
                             <div id='result'></div> \
                             </div>\
                           </div>";

      return template;

    }

    let previewContainer = document.createElement('div');
    previewContainer.setAttribute('class', 'preview-container');
    previewContainer.dataset.resourceid = data.resourceId;
    previewContainer.dataset.resourcetype = data.resourceType;
    previewContainer.dataset.cachekey = data.cacheKey;
    if (data.resourceType === "channel") {
      previewContainer.innerHTML = '<img src="' + data.preview.high.url + '" />';
    } else {
      previewContainer.innerHTML = data.preview.items[0].player.embedHtml;
    }
    container.appendChild(previewContainer);

    previewContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', settings(data.id, data.title));

    progress.style.display = "none";

    window.scroll({
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });

  }).DTApi('DT', 'preview', cacheKey, resourceId, resourceType);

}

function search(page, key) {

  const progress = document.querySelector("#progress");
  progress.style.display = "block";
  // If there's a page token, set it
  var pageToken = page || "";
  var key = key || "";

  let term = document.querySelector('#search-input').value;
  let checked = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="queryArg"]:checked');
  let prev = document.querySelector("#prev");
  let next = document.querySelector("#next");
  let total = document.querySelector("#total-results");

  // Get the checked search types
  let args = {};
  args.types = [];

  // TODO: Validate that there is at least _one_ checked box
  // Default to videos
  checked.forEach(function(el) {
    args.types.push(el.value);
  });

  args.pageToken = page;
  args.key = key;

  const container = document.querySelector('#search-result');
  container.innerText = ('Searching...');
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(result) {
    container.innerText = '';
    let data = JSON.parse(result);

    console.log(data.data.length);

    if (data.data.length === 0) {
      container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<p>No videos found in your search! Try another search term.</p>');
    }

    let videoContainers = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
      videoContainers.push(data.data.splice(0, 10))
    }

    console.log(videoContainers);

    videoContainers.forEach(function(items) {
      items.forEach(function(vid) {
        container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', vid);
      });
    });

    if (data.nextPage == undefined) {
      next.disabled = true;
    } else {
      next.disabled = false;
      next.dataset.page = data.nextPage;
      next.dataset.cachekey = data.nextKey;
    }

    if (data.prevPage == undefined) {
      prev.disabled = true;
    } else {
      prev.disabled = false;
      prev.dataset.page = data.prevPage;
      prev.dataset.cachekey = data.prevKey;
    }

    document.querySelector('#pagination').style.display = 'block';
    progress.style.display = "none";
  }).DTApi('DT', 'search', term, args);
}

function getPage(el) {

  let page = el.dataset.page;
  let key = el.dataset.cachekey;
  search(page, key)

}

function paginate(array, page) {

  return array.slice(page * 10, 10)

}

$("#doc").click(function() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showFrames).getVideos();
})

$("#comments").click(function() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showFrames).getCommentData();
});

function showFrames(frames) {
  $("#embed").empty();
  console.log(frames.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) {
    $("#embed").append("<iframe src='https://youtube.com/embed/" + frames[i] + "' width='100%' height='480' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>");
  }
}
```

```css
#progress {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 70px;
  top: -5.5px;
}

.search {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.search>input[type="text"] {
  width: 60%;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.search>#search-args {
  width: 60%;
}

#search-result {
  margin-top: 15px;
  min-height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}

#search-result>div {
  transition: box-shadow ease-in-out 0.25s;
  width: 300px;
  height: 180px
}

#search-result>.video-container:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#pagination {
  display: none;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

#preview {
  margin: 15px auto 0;
}

.settings {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 35%;
  position: relative;
}

#result {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

#preview img {
  width: 45%;
  height: auto;
}

#preview iframe,
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#preview iframe+.settings {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

#preview img+.settings {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.settings>label {
  line-height: 36px;
}

#link-text {
  visibility: hidden;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  width: 60%;
}

#toggle:checked~#link-text {
  visibility: visible;
}

.settings>button {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.video-container {
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin: 5px;
}

.type-icon {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
}

.action-container {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 65px;
  background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.75);
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
}

.action-container>span {
  padding: 5px;
  line-height: 65px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

span:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.15s;
}

.video-container:hover>.action-container {
  opacity: 1;
}

#embed {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#srcSelect {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#srcSelect span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 15px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.8);
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 180, 0.8);
  padding: 12px;
}

#srcSelect span:hover {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 180, 1);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<base target="_top">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css">

<div class="search">
  <input type="text" id="search-input" value="" />
  <button id="search-btn" class="action" onclick="search(null)">Search</button>
  <button onclick="document.querySelector('#search-result').innerHTML = ''">Clear</button>
  <svg id="progress" version="1.1" id="loader-1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="40px" height="40px" viewBox="0 0 40 40" enable-background="new 0 0 40 40" xml:space="preserve">
      <path opacity="0.2" fill="#00d" d="M20.201,5.169c-8.254,0-14.946,6.692-14.946,14.946c0,8.255,6.692,14.946,14.946,14.946
        s14.946-6.691,14.946-14.946C35.146,11.861,28.455,5.169,20.201,5.169z M20.201,31.749c-6.425,0-11.634-5.208-11.634-11.634
        c0-6.425,5.209-11.634,11.634-11.634c6.425,0,11.633,5.209,11.633,11.634C31.834,26.541,26.626,31.749,20.201,31.749z"/>
      <path fill="#00d" d="M26.013,10.047l1.654-2.866c-2.198-1.272-4.743-2.012-7.466-2.012h0v3.312h0
        C22.32,8.481,24.301,9.057,26.013,10.047z">
      <animateTransform attributeType="xml"
        attributeName="transform"
        type="rotate"
        from="0 20 20"
        to="360 20 20"
        dur="0.5s"
        repeatCount="indefinite"/>
      </path>
    </svg>
  <div id="search-args">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="queryArg" value="video" checked="checked"/>Videos</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="queryArg" value="channel" />Channels</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="queryArg" value="playlist" />Playlists</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="preview"></div>
<div id="pagination">
  <button id="prev" data-page="" onclick="getPage(this)">Previous</button>
  <button id="next" data-page="" onclick="getPage(this)">Next</button>
</div>
<div id="search-result"></div>
```

The error i'm getting is :

> "uncaught reference error: google is not defined"

the error says the issue occurs within line 360. i copied the whole ass code, line for line, from the original editor, where line 360 is:

```
        } else {
```

the hell should i do? i have looked over the code relentlessly for the past 3 days and have found no evidence of an error other than the fact the search results never come through. i am truly stumped on this one and i need the coding cavalry.

Comment: The console tells you what's wrong

Comment: `"Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined"`

Comment: have you defined google js api?

Comment: As in `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=..."
    async defer></script>`

Comment: Show console errors. See [mre]

Comment: @javascript tag users `google` api is automatically loaded on the client browser, when served from Google servers.

Answer (score 0):

As a user said in the comments, `google` object is automatically imported in the html file when you're using Apps Script [1]. You need to delete this line: `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=..." async defer></script>`, which is causing the error as explained in this other question [2].

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run

[2] [Google Maps API throws "Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined" only when using AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229695/google-maps-api-throws-uncaught-referenceerror-google-is-not-defined-only-whe)